# DNS Clean command not found

Tags: release-hera, internet

Why is there no such command in elementary to clear the DNS cache?

`sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean start` command not found

Answer (score 2):

Since elementaryOS 5 and newer, `systemd-resolve` handles flushing the DNS cache.
This was an upstream change made in Ubuntu 17.04 according to [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/929478/1117671).
Use the following command to flush your DNS cache.

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```